# use of <logger> element is logback.xml

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I created a simple web application with `slf4j-logback` logging. I used the below configuration that prints log statements to `mylog.log` file.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="fileAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${catalina.base}/logs/mylog.log</File>

        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The above worked fine.

I came across one `logger` element as

```
<logger name="mylog" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</logger>
```

What is the use of this `logger` element? Will it make any difference as my first configuration worked fine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<logger>` is not needed because you are using `<root>` logger. The `root` configuration is inherited by children `logger` configurations and can be overriden. See [Logback configuration documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any logger define by name "mylog" in your application.
if not, this is the reason it is not working.

try this...

```
<Logger name="test01.test02" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</Logger>
```

test01 = package;
test02= class